# Apply missing const to a file, project or solution

Tags: c++, resharper

During the static analysis, ReSharper often correctly recognizes, when a local variable may be `const` (aside from special cases, where `#ifdef` is used to distinct between different configurations/platforms).

Is there an option in ReSharper C++ to apply missing `const` on local variables automatically to the file, project or solution?

Comment: Even if ReSharper can find some cases, it's not always those cases it find *should* be `const`. Having it automatically refactor the code for all cases could lead to other problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The responsibility lies in the hands of the developer and depends on the case he is facing: If you have a lot of small (well tested) functions where 99% of the `const`s are correct, it is faster to bulk change them and review the changes for the 1% case it doesn't fit.

Comment: My answer was deleted but here it is a comment. Sorry, there's no bulk fix for this yet. Please vote for the corresponding feature request to receive an update when it becomes available - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-20247.

Comment: @Igor _My answer was deleted_  Why?????